# @nuxtjs/auth login method calls a user method upon completion

Tags: asp.net-core, nuxt.js

I'm using the nuxtjs/auth module to authenticate a user, with the backend written in .NET Core

When configuring the nuxtjs/auth package, I add the following to `nuxt.config.js`

```
//nuxt.config.js
  .
  .

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'users/authenticate', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data.token' },
        }
      }
    }
  },

  .
  .
```

the login function called when clicking 'login' looks like this

```
  async login () {
    try {
      await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data: {
          Username: this.username,
          Password: this.password
        }
      })

      this.$router.push('/')
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e) <-------------------
      this.error = e.response.data.message
    }
  }
```

The `console.log(e)` returns the following message:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (commons.app.js:565)
    at settle (commons.app.js:728)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (commons.app.js:98)
```

And in the console I also get

```
GET https://example.com/api/api/auth/user 404 (Not Found)
```

So it would seem that upon completing the initial authentication request, the nuxtjs/auth module calls 'user' in the API.
My backend is written in NET Core

So my question is, am I supposed to write in the NET Core backend, because the documentation for the nuxtjs/api package does not seem to explain how the basic usage of the module works